# 8000 Amps across a 1 A diode for 0.2 uS

Tags: diodes, basic, pulse

Assuming that the diode is rated for 20 kV and the pulse is only 250 V, will a 250 V 8 kA pulse that lasts 0.2 uS break a 20 kV 1 A diode? This also assumes that the diode recieves 10 of these pulses every second for 5 seconds.

For reference, terminal are axial leads and the diode is a HV rectifier diode.

Comment: Read the devices data sheet. Many will show limits for pulses of some duration.  Outside of that, you've become a test engineer. 8000 x the rated current seems like a lo tho, even for a short duration.  Will the bonded leads fail? Will the semiconductor fail? Hard to say.

Comment: Semiconductors have imperfections in their substrate. That means that you can't just have n times the current if you reduce the pulse length by 1/n as n approaches infinite You eventually hit a limit where pulse is so short that the heat cannot dissipate fast enough to be evenly distributed and hotspots develop and those hotspots fail first. Where is this limit? I'm not sure but I'm quite certain 8000% of the rated continuous current is well beyond it.

Comment: My guess is that you'd hit 250V Vf long before you hit 8000A. If 8000A is a **violent** explosion 20 series junctions (?) with 12V Vf across them sounds pretty bad too.You must have almost zero inductance to be able to get di/dt like that.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Heh, yeah. I never even considered the voltage drop increase as current increases. Not that it really matters. A popped diode is a popped diode whether by overvoltage or heat when driving running it at 8000%.

Comment: @dknguyen Not even 8000% but 800000%

Comment: The maximum voltage rating is for **reverse** bias and the maximum current rating is for **forward bias**. Relaxing the reverse bias voltage limit doesn't change the forward bias limits.

Comment: 8000 Amps **across** a 1A diode? Depends on what is carrying the current _across_ the diode.

Comment: @pericynthion I no math today.

Comment: Those numbers sound a lot like transient surge testing.  Have you looked at TVS diodes and MOVs?

Comment: Spehro makes a point: I calculate that about 1.5 cm of coax going out to the diode and another 1.5 cm of coax coming back from it (1 cm outer diameter with 3mm diameter center wire) would keep the inductance down just barely low enough to make it work. That said, the diode will have Ohmic resistance and I'm pretty sure that the Ohmic part, plus all the current-crowding issues, dominate the problem. The inductance *might* be solvable, but probably isn't.